# Run single .html file as .php?

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form on a site with an .html extension that needs to be run as .php.  I know you can use mod rewrite to treat all .html files as .php, but can you do it for just one file?

TIA...

Steve

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply change the extension to `.php`?

Comment: You could use a mod_rewrite for the specific path, but why not just change your filename to whatever.php instead?

Comment: Why do you border to change only for one file. Do it for all. Or rename your file to .php

Comment: probably belongs to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: As a website user, I'd feel betrayed, somehow, that although I was requesting a ".html" file, a script had been executed. Can't really explain why. This just seems very odd.

Comment: @Tormalek Geret'kal. I hope thi is a joke. There are "html" scripts all over the web, Even a lot o images arereally just PHP scripts! Thats i one o the reasons why yo should nit allow users to post images that are hosted onanother server.

Comment: there is a VERY dirty hack. I will not post thisas as an answer because it is just too dirty. Since directory names may include "." you can actually create a directory named "contact.html"  and put a index.php inside! works for images and zip files as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <Files bar.html>
 SetHandler php-script
 </Files>
```

or something similar in either a .htaccess or your apache config.

Comment: Do you get an error? If you put it in an .htaccess, are you sure that's enabled? Did the logfiles tell you anything?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache, try to add this to your .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```

(courtesy [kavoir.com](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-run-html-as-php.html))

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

If you want to do this for only one file , you have to set a unique extension (like *.xyz*) . If you choose *.html* all .html files executes as a PHP file.

Comment: I think this is what he is saying he does not want to do.  Though the OP did not mention this technique, so I suppose it is a valid answer.